# Detecting the concentration of chlorpromazine

Tags: electrochemistry, drugs

Is there a way to detect the concentration of chlorpromazine in a small sample ; ex: human saliva, using electro-chemical analysis? Does the sensor necessarily have to be a bulky piece of lab equipment or are there smaller sensors available for that kind of test?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

A cursory online search furnished

1. *Graphene paste electrode for detection of chlorpromazine* by *Mohammad Hadi Parvin* in *Electrochemistry Communications*, **2011**, *13*, 366-369 ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.elecom.2011.01.027)).
2. *A multipurpose Voltammetric Sensor for the Determination of 
   Chlorpromazine in Presence of Acetaminophen, Uric Acid, 
   Dopamine and Ascorbic Acid* by *Binesh Unnikrishnan, Pei-Chi Hsu, and Shen-Ming Chen* in *Int. J. Electrochem. Sci.*, **2012**, *7*, 11414-11425 ([PDF](http://www.electrochemsci.org/papers/vol7/71111414.pdf)).